# STM32 ADC sinewave samples looking choppy and block-like despite high sampling rate

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, embedded

I'm trying to read a sinewave off from my signal generator with STM32 ADC and reproduce the same wave on my DAC, this is the result

[image: This is what my wave looks like in low frequency about 300 Hz]

This is what my wave looks like in low frequency about 300 Hz

and as I increase the frequency of the sinewave I'm trying to sample, it gets choppier and choppier until it becomes essentially square at around 3k .

[image]

The above is at a higher frequency and you can see the block start appearing.

[image]

The green wave is from the function generator, it's a pretty bad one so it's clipped, I can't get the offset very right on this one. The frequency of the waves as seen on scope is 1.9 khz

[image]

Finally at 4 Khz it stops looking like a sinewave. But this is really strange since I used a 10uS delay between sampling so sampling rate should really be that low to give me these square bars.I'm wondering if the ADC is busted because a fault signal generator i was using accidentally gave it a 10 volt DC offset which might have really fried it up.

My ADC setup code looks like this

```
void configure_ADC2_Channel_0(void)
{
__HAL_RCC_ADC2_CLK_ENABLE(); // enable clock to ADC2 module
    myADC2Handle.Instance = ADC2; // create an instance of ADC2
    myADC2Handle.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B; // select 12-bit resolution 
    myADC2Handle.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV; //select  single conversion as a end of conversion event
    myADC2Handle.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT; // set digital output data right justified
    myADC2Handle.Init.ClockPrescaler =ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV8; 
    HAL_ADC_Init(&myADC2Handle); // initialize AD2 with myADC2Handle configuration settings
    
  /*select ADC2 channel */
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef Channel_AN0; // create an instance of ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef
    Channel_AN0.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0; // select analog channel 0
    Channel_AN0.Rank = 1; // set rank to 1
    Channel_AN0.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES; // set sampling time to 15 clock cycles
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&myADC2Handle, &Channel_AN0); // select channel_0 for ADC2 module. 
}
```

The active part of the code is like this

```
        HAL_ADC_Start(&myADC2Handle); // start A/D conversion
        if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&myADC2Handle, 5) == HAL_OK) //check if conversion is completed
        {
        Adc_value  = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&myADC2Handle); // read digital value and save it inside uint32_t variable
        }
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&myADC2Handle); // stop conversion 
        x[20] = Adc_value;
    
        
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    HAL_DAC_SetValue(&DAC_Config, DAC_CHANNEL_2, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, (int)(Adc_value));
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14);
    delay_us(10);
```

The delay code with which I do delay_us(x) looks like this

Delay code (c file)

```
#include "TA_STM32_Delay_Us.h"


/**
 * @brief  Initializes DWT_Clock_Cycle_Count for DWT_Delay_us function
 * @return Error DWT counter
 *         1: clock cycle counter not started
 *         0: clock cycle counter works
 */
uint32_t Delay_Us_Init(void) {
  /* Disable TRC */
  CoreDebug->DEMCR &= ~CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // ~0x01000000;
  /* Enable TRC */
  CoreDebug->DEMCR |=  CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // 0x01000000;

  /* Disable clock cycle counter */
  DWT->CTRL &= ~DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //~0x00000001;
  /* Enable  clock cycle counter */
  DWT->CTRL |=  DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; //0x00000001;

  /* Reset the clock cycle counter value */
  DWT->CYCCNT = 0;

     /* 3 NO OPERATION instructions */
     __ASM volatile ("NOP");
     __ASM volatile ("NOP");
  __ASM volatile ("NOP");

  /* Check if clock cycle counter has started */
     if(DWT->CYCCNT)
     {
       return 0; /*clock cycle counter started*/
     }
     else
  {
    return 1; /*clock cycle counter not started*/
  }
}
```

Delay code, headerfile

```
#ifndef TA_STM32_DELAY_US_H
#define TA_STM32_DELAY_US_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/**
 * @brief  Initializes DWT_Cycle_Count for DWT_Delay_us function
 * @return Error DWT counter
 *         1: DWT counter Error
 *         0: DWT counter works
 */
uint32_t Delay_Us_Init(void);



/**
 * @brief  This function provides a delay (in microseconds)
 * @param  microseconds: delay in microseconds
 */
__STATIC_INLINE void delay_us(volatile uint32_t microseconds)
{
  uint32_t clk_cycle_start = DWT->CYCCNT;

  /* Go to number of cycles for system */
  microseconds *= (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000000);

  /* Delay till end */
  while ((DWT->CYCCNT - clk_cycle_start) < microseconds);
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

I want to know what might be causing this problem, I don't expect jagged edges with such a good sampling rate giving me problems at 4khz. Could it be my ADC is fried ?

Comment: If you don't trust the hardware ("a fault signal generator i was using accidentally gave it a 10 volt DC offset which might have really fried it up."), then take a few steps back. Put a flat DC level into the ADC and see what results you get out when you vary it slowly. Check that the output of the DAC changes in proportion to the change you apply to the ADC input.

Comment: @brhans that's exactly what I did to confirm whether ADC and DAC were working, I sent a flat DC, measured with multimeter, added 2000 to ADC value and made it print on DAC. It worked pretty well for a range of values when varied slowly and I confirmed it with multimeter.  The kind of weirdness in the picture seems only to happen with higher frequencies.

Comment: I see you're toggling a few pins in Port-D on every sample. Do those pins toggle at the rate you expect them to?

Comment: @brhans yeah they do, when I use the delay microsecond and put in something like 500000 I get what looks roughly correct

Comment: What is up with the blocky signal, it isn't aliasing is it?

Comment: I'm more interested in whether they toggle at the expected rate when you're trying to sample somewhere in the kHz range where things look like they're going haywire. And no those symptoms doesn't look to me like typical aliasing.

Comment: It looks like sample rate is much lower than expected. Put some pin-toggling code inside `if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion...` block, to check the actual `Adc_value` update rate.

Comment: @brhans so it looks like even without any delay function at all, the ADC sampling is happening at 8Khz, which is super strange since I set my clock at 168 Mhz

Comment: I can't figure out what's eating so much performance

Comment: Add more GPIO toggles to narrow it down. For example, toggle GPIOD12 before & after the ADC conversion, GPIOD13 before & after the DAC_SetValue, etc. That should help you to get closer to the cause.

Comment: @brhans i did this by removing the ADC conversion, the DAC output and GPIOD in code all separately, turns out  ADC is the one slowing it down like crazy. But very very strangely with no code running and just GPIO pin toggling the toggling frequency seemed to be 330khz.That's the frequency the main loop is running at. With the ADC conversion it seems to be 14 Khz (after I pushed my clock to 168, it was lower when i examined the code after I made that comment) .

All this seems crazy slow to me, this isn't what's expected, right?

Comment: To get such a slow sample rate it seems like your ADC is being clocked very slowly - somewhere in the 2MHz range. Are you sure you have the APB2 peripheral clock configured correctly? With 168MHz HCLK you should be able to get the APB2 peripherals as high as 84MHz. Divide that by 8 for the ADC (as you're already doing) and it should be able to do a 12-bit conversion in under 1.5uSec.

Comment: @brhans I'm not sure how you went from a 2 Mhz clock to some 14 kHz sampling? What about the mainloop with no code except the toggle, is some 300kHz what's expected out of a 168 Mhz clock?

Comment: I get to 2MHz from the ADC config you've posted. 14kHz * 15 * 8 == 1.68MHz. Rounded up to 2MHz. Note that I'm referring to the *ADC clock* which comes from APB2, not the core clock (HCLK). HCLK gets divided down to produce the APB2 clock. If you haven't configured this correctly then that's probably the problem.